# How to apply "WithEvents" trigger?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have this code in a module:

```
Private WithEvents objNewMailItems As Outlook.Items

Public Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace

    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set mainInboxItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub mainInboxItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)
    Call MandarMail.sendOutlookEmail
    ' //this send another email...
End Sub
```

This is my first time using a trigger. Visual Basic for Applications does not recognize this:

```
Private WithEvents objNewMailItems As Outlook.Items
```

I'm using Outlook 2013

Comment: WithEvents needs to be in either `ThisOutlookSession` or a class module - I don't think it fires in a normal module (someone correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Is the code being written in Outlook or another Office application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If written in Outlook this should work.
You've declared `objNewMailItems` but used `mainInboxItems`

```
Dim WithEvents objNewMailItems As Items

Public Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objNewMailItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

End Sub

Private Sub objNewMailItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

    'This will fire when you receive a new email.
    Debug.Assert False

End Sub
```

Edit - I've found with this that after a while Outlook disables the macros, so have to manually run `StartUp` each day.  Doesn't matter what I try with the Trust Centre settings - it keeps disabling my code.

Comment: works with this code Dim WithEvents objNewMailItems As Items

Public Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set objNewMailItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

End Sub

Private Sub objNewMailItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

    'This will fire when you receive a new email.
   
   MsgBox ("mail recibi")

End Sub

Comment: I'm upvoting this answer mainly because of the edit, finding that Outlook effectively disables macros after a while. I currently have an open question on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48548203/withevents-object-in-outlook-vba-eventually-fails-to-raise-event). I think Outlook is just disabling events on custom objects (`WithEvents`), not _all_ events

Comment: `Dim WithEvents objNewMailItems As Items` Compile Error: Only valid in object module. Outlook 2019. Module

Answer (score 0):

Thx Darren. I modificated your code and now works fine:

Dim WithEvents objNewMailItems As Items

Public Sub Application_Startup()

```
Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application

Set olApp = Outlook.Application
Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set objNewMailItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

End Sub

Private Sub objNewMailItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object)

'This will fire when you receive a new email.

MsgBox ("mail recibi")

End Sub
```