# WithEvents object in Outlook VBA eventually fails to raise event

Tags: vba, outlook

Okay, looks like someone has encountered this problem before, but I didn't see any further comments or solutions. See the Edit in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34720620/problems-with-withevents-in-firtstrigger).

My situation is like this.

I am running Outlook 2013 under Win10 x64 with an Exchange email account. I sometimes run Outlook for several days to a week or more at a time without closing it.

I want to raise an event when a new item is added to the Sent Mail folder. This needs to occur after the `Application ItemSend` event because, let's say, I want to delete the message after it is sent, which you cannot do from within the `ItemSend` event handler.

So I have the following code:

```
Public WithEvents goSent As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    'Establish the global object for the folder we want to monitor.

    Set goSent = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items

End Sub

Private Sub goSent_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    'Do stuff here.

End Sub
```

Everything works beautifully for a day or longer, but eventually the `ItemAdd` event handler stops firing. If I enter the VBA editor and manually run `Application_Startup`, then it starts working again.

[Edit:] One other bit of information: The "built-in" events, like `Application ItemSend`, always seem to fire reliably no matter how long Outlook has been running.

[Edit 2:] This time, I let things go for a day after the event stopped firing. I opened the VBA editor and put a breakpoint in the `Application ItemSend` procedure. When it stopped, I queried the `goSent` object and found that (a) it still existed (rather than being `Nothing`), but (b) it had only the items in it that were there yesterday, presumably at the time it became "untethered" from the Sent Mail items collection. When I submitted a new `Set` statement in the Immediate window, it immediately began to work again.

[Edit 3:] I noticed that the MSDN documentation says to put event handlers for custom objects--like my `ItemAdd` event--in *class modules*. I have mine in ThisOutlookSession, but it was my understanding that ThisOutlookSession *is* a class module. Is there a problem with that?

Any idea why this would happen and what to do about it? I considered adding an event handler for `Application ItemSend` and just reassigning the `goSent` object every time that's fired, but it doesn't address the underlying problem.

[Edit 4:] For a while now, I've had a `Set` statement in the `Application ItemSend` handler, and that seems to have *mostly* taken care of things, even though it's a workaround, not really a solution. It appears to fail when I have delayed delivery on a sent item for an extended time, and I don't send any further messages in the meantime. Then the `goSent` object disconnects from the Sent Mail collection, and the message is actually sent from the Outbox after that point and before `Application ItemSend` fires again.

Thanks!

---

[Edit 5:] **Unrelated to original issue:** I discovered that my macros fail to accomplish what I want with an Exchange server that is in *online* mode (i.e., not cached mode) if I have messages in the Outbox with delayed delivery and Outlook is closed when the delivery time passes. In online mode, Exchange itself sends these messages and adds them to the Sent Mail folder on the server, so when Outlook reopens, the messages are already in the Sent Mail collection and no event fires. Which makes sense. See discussion [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/exchange/en-US/7ced48f4-075d-4079-a050-d56cedab9440/message-will-not-send-if-outlook-is-closed-when-using-delay-delivery-option?forum=exchangesvrclientslegacy). Looks like I would need to add something to my `Application_Startup` macro to look for messages sent since Outlook last closed.

Comment: *Everything works beautifully for a day or longer* - why? Try closing Outlook when you leave at night, and opening it when you come in the next morning.

Comment: Actually, I used to have a good reason to keep Outlook open all the time. Let's pretend I still do. So closing and reopening Outlook would probably "solve" the problem in the same way that reassigning the `goSent` object in the `ItemSend` event handler would probably work. Neither one actually addresses the underlying issue.

Comment: Could it possibly have something to do with losing connection to the Exchange Server for a few moments?

Comment: Is that an online or a cached Exchange profile?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue and never found a proper solution. What I did was I wrote a little batch script that closes and opens outlook app, then I set a task in task scheduler to run it every hour outside of my working hours. You can also do it easily in vbs.

Comment: Sounds like a brute-force solution to an intractable problem. Sometimes, that's all you can do.

Comment: I agree it's not perfect and I'm not happy with it, but it does the job. Hopefully you'll find better solution!